Example using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller
Background
I would like an example of using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller to control a robot with ros2_control. I am trying to use this graphical interface to control the UR3e robot arm in Gazebo.
So far, I have installed rqt_joint_trajectory_controller from here, and also downloaded/installed the official UR Gazebo Simulator here as well as the required description package here.
Problem Statement
When I launch the simulator with the joint_trajectory_controller via:
ros2 launch ur_simulation_gz ur_sim_control.launch.py

and then launch the rqt window with
ros2 run rqt_joint_trajectory_controller rqt_joint_trajectory_controller --force-discover -t -v

and then select the proper controller manager, I get the following output:
Waiting for the robot_description!
Waiting for the robot_description!
Waiting for the robot_description!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../ws/build/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.py", line 426, in _update_cmd_cb
    pos = self._joint_pos[name]["position"]
KeyError: 'position'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/...ws/build/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller.py", line 426, in _update_cmd_cb
    pos = self._joint_pos[name]["position"]
KeyError: 'position'

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please provide an example of using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller in ros2? That would be appreciated.
System Information
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS Version: ros2 humble
Gazebo Version: Ignition 6.16.0
Additional Info
I know that my ros2_control system is working with the joint trajectory controller, because I can make the robot move properly with the following command:
ros2 launch ur_robot_driver test_joint_trajectory_controller.launch.py

after installing the ur_robot_driver package from here

Welcome at RSE. This seems like a bug, or a missing exception for some incompatible configuration.
Can you compile and test example_1? This should work.

Example 1 is working. To replicate:
ros2 launch ros2_control_demo_example_1 rrbot.launch.py
Followed in another terminal by:
ros2 control load_controller joint_trajectory_position_controller --set-state inactive && ros2 control switch_controllers --activate joint_trajectory_position_controller --deactivate forward_position_controller && rqt

and then I can open `Plugins > Robot Tools > Joint trajectory controller`, select my controller manager and controller, press the red button, slide the sliders, then press the green button, and wait.

Please note that immediately after opening rqt, I see the message:
Waiting for the robot_description! Waiting for the robot_description! Waiting for the robot_description! but the KeyError: 'position' goes away. There must be something wrong with my setup with the ur_simulation_gz package....
